# Unable to Log exceptions

Tags: c#, iis

This is my method which i'm using to log the exceptions of an application. It is not working in visual studio but working fine in IIS. If I change the formats "PresentMonth" and "Filename" , it is working in VS but not on IIS. I don't know what's wrong.

```
 public static void WriteLog(string sExceptionName)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter log;
            //String Filepath = "C:\\Quasar_Logs\\";
            String Filepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();
            String PresentMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("-MMM-yy");
            String Filename = "Quasar_Log"+ PresentMonth +".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(Filepath + Filename))
            {
                log = new StreamWriter(Filepath + Filename);
            }
            else
            {
                log = File.AppendText(Filepath + Filename);
            }

            log.WriteLine("Data Time:" + DateTime.Now +"\n\n");
            //log.WriteLine("Exception Name:" + sExceptionName);
            log.WriteLine(sExceptionName);             
            //log.WriteLine("Error Line No.:" + nErrorLineNo); 
            log.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../Access/UnabletoLog.htm");
            WriteLog("Line Number: " + ex.ToString());             
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its likely a permissions issue in where you're trying to write to.

Comment: @BugFinder Earlier i have created in 'C' drive and now i changed it to 'E' drive, it worked. But my doubt is, when i have the file in C drive, it worked in IIS but not in VS and vice versa if i change the formats.?

Comment: because in VS its running as you, in IIS its running at something else Id guess..  You should be able to grant permissions

Comment: @BugFinder Anyways, it worked for me now. Thanks for solution, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Create the directory first if file not exists, matbe the directory does not exists, SreamWriter creates the file an not the directory where the file is in. This worked for me:

```
        if (!File.Exists(FilePath + FileName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath);
            log = new StreamWriter(FilePath + FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            log = File.AppendText(FilePath + FileName);
        }
```

Comment: @Timon Post The file do exists in the destination.